# How to import data from another spyder file

Tags: python, spyder

I am working on a Spyder project which has many files. I run one file and use the output as input to next file. For every run of last file, all previous files run which consumes a lot of time for each run of last file (I run last file many times but previous files only once). Is it possible to use output of previous files as input to next/last file without running all previous files. Thanks